# SQL Server - Select using like and some kind of regex

Tags: sql-server, regex

I would like to perform a select that find every rows that have something like $Value(SomeNumber)$. The part **Value** and **SomeNumber** is dynamic.

How can I build a select to match this conditions?

I'm trying this way:

```
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(255)
SET @VALUE = 'Badass(5)' -- it could Badass, Badass(XXX) or Badass(XX)
SELECT Txt FROM Employers where Txt LIKE '%$' + @VALUE + '$%' OR 
    TxT LIKE '%$' + @VALUE + '\(\d{2}\)$%'
```

Comment: I have no idea what your search criteria is. Does the search change, so sometimes you are looking for Badass(5) and other times Badass(10) and times SweetButtercup(42)? Or are you trying to find everything that matches [[:alpha:]]+([[:digit:]]+)? Or something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSSQL has poor builtin support for regular expressions, two options are

a) Creating a CLR stored routine, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

b) Using VBScript.RegExp in TSQL, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/05/11/416392.aspx

Both need at least MSSQL 2005.

Comment: @placplacboom and Fernando: I would strongly suggest avoiding the OLE Automation procedures (i.e. `sp_OA*` ) that are the basis of option #2 (using VBScript.RegExp). The OLE Automation procs, as well as Extended Stored Procedures, are deprecated as of SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2):

- CLR package including Regex CLR Functions [Sql#](http://www.sqlsharp.com)
- [LIKE on TechNet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [PATINDEX on TechNet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)
- [PATINDEX Workbench - Phil Factor](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/patindex-workbench/)

If you want Regex and can use CLR, I would use [Sql#](http://www.sqlsharp.com).

Not quite sure the rules of your search based on what is available in the question, but this might lead somewhere:

```sql
  declare @value varchar(255) = 'Badass(5)' -- it could Badass, Badass(XXX) or Badass(XX)/

  declare @parenthesis int = isnull(nullif(charindex('(',@value),0),256)
  declare @search_str varchar(255) = '%$'+left(@value,@parenthesis-1)
  declare @somenumber varchar(255) = case @parenthesis when 256 then '%$%' else '([0-9]%)$%' end
  declare @search varchar(255) = @search_str + @somenumber

  --select value=@value, search_str=@search_str, somenumber=@somenumber, search=@search

select StringMatch=case when rowtxt like @search then 1 else 0 end
  , value=@value
  , rowtxt
from (select rowtxt='This is SamSaffron $Badass$'
  union all select 'This is BrentO $Badass(12)$'
  union all select 'This is AaronBertrand $Badass(20141222)$ '
  union all select 'This is SqlZim $Not As Badass(N)$ '
  union all select 'This is SqlZim $Badass(ButNoNumber)$ '
  union all select 'This is SqlZim $Badass(1Number)$ '
) i
```

`@value = 'BadAss(5)' returns`

```
IsMatch     value            rowtxt
----------- ---------------- -----------------------------------------
0           Badass(5)        This is SamSaffron $Badass$
1           Badass(5)        This is BrentO $Badass(12)$
1           Badass(5)        This is AaronBertrand $Badass(20141222)$ 
0           Badass(5)        This is SqlZim $Not As Badass(N)$ 
0           Badass(5)        This is SqlZim $Badass(ButNoNumber)$ 
1           Badass(5)        This is SqlZim $Badass(1Number)$
```

`@value = 'BadAss' returns`

```
IsMatch     value            rowtxt
----------- ---------------- -----------------------------------------
1           Badass           This is SamSaffron $Badass$
1           Badass           This is BrentO $Badass(12)$
1           Badass           This is AaronBertrand $Badass(20141222)$ 
0           Badass           This is SqlZim $Not As Badass(N)$ 
1           Badass           This is SqlZim $Badass(ButNoNumber)$ 
1           Badass           This is SqlZim $Badass(1Number)$
```